# .M2P file extention to image file extension, image processing

Tags: image, data-conversion, mpeg

I have a .m2p file (which is an image file i believe that contains many images, kinda like a video of still images) that I would like to convert to any image file (preferably .png or .jpg).
Does anyone know if there is a possible way to do so?
 Does anyone know how to convert these, *using a script*, to a different file extension essentially. Extract out all the images from a `.m2p` file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not ask the author why he chooses to use some non-standard format for his images and if he has tools available to extract the contents?

Comment: @MarkSetchell These are just sample images, i don't have access to the actual images I am using at the moment. Those images are old and ones that must be used.

Comment: [It looks like](https://www.google.com/search?q=m2p+file+extension) a file with the .m2p extension is an MPEG-2 file. That means it contains a video and/or audio stream.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer to this.

Can simply just use `ffmpeg` (for Mac atleast).

Images:
To grab a still from a certain time:
`ffmpeg -i video.m2p -ss 00:00:07.000 -vframes 1 thumb.png`

Videos:
To convert *m2p* to *mp4*
`ffmpeg -i example.m2p -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -acodec aac example.mp4 -hide_banner`

Random: I used the `slow` preset just so it outputs a better quality video